# Remote EJB from HttpServlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, openejb

I want to call a remote EJB from a different EJB server. I've Remote EJB's deployed on OpenEJB ,then I will call them from Glassfish `HTTPServlet`. I know on local EJB i can do @EJB annotation but I want user to "authenticate" remote OpenEJB server from Glassfish servlet.

on OpenEJB:

```
//OpenEJB server at 192.168.10.12
public class AdminManager {
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Admin called this method");
    }
}
```

Glassfish Servlet

```
//Glassfish servlet at 192.168.10.10
public class AdminManage extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
            p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ejbd://192.168.10.12:4201");
            // user and pass optional

      String userName = req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
      String password = req.getSession().getAttribute("password");
            p.put("java.naming.security.principal", userName );
            p.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "password );

            final InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);

            final AdminManagerRemote myBean = (MyBean) ctx.lookup("AdminManagerRemote");
            try {
                myBean.test();
            } catch(Exception epx) {
                resp.sendRedirect(resp.encodeRedirectURL("/login"));
            }
    }
}
```

Okay this seems a solution but this is not "good" solution for me.
Everytime authenticating to openejb sucks , like this;

```
  String userName = req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
  String password = req.getSession().getAttribute("password");
  p.put("java.naming.security.principal", userName );
  p.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "password );
```

And the code is not clean.
  I want user to authenticate only once and call ejb methods.
  Is there any better solution then this?

Can I combine Glassfish HTTP authentication with remote openEJB authentication?
I mean when user authenticates to Glassfish HTTP server , i want openEJB authenticate as well.
This is really making me mad. what solution is good to escape from spagetti codes?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Authenticate to OpenEJB when the  user logs into Glassfish, store the EJB stub in the user session and reuse it later. I fear you will need to implement some EJB 2.x inteface for the [serialization of the stub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6554959/217862) (so-called *handle*) to work.
2. Implement a cache where you store the EJB stubs. If a stub for the given username/password is in the cache, reuse it, if not, authenticate. The cache is a static object, it could be created for instance with Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html). This violates the spec (you should not use static to share information between servlets), but since it's a cache, it's not a big deal. It would even work in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try introducing Service Locator Pattern to eliminate the redundancy in the code & hide the underlying details & complexity of creating initial context, JNDI lookup etc.

You can cache remote home interface `EJBHome` & then re-use it later when required.

Can refer [Core J2EE Patterns - Service Locator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servicelocator-137181.html) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What about Kerberos ? Someone know kerberos solution ? 
Login to all remote servers with TGS.

But there is no sample for that on internet.
And its so evil hard to install kerberos with openldap.